# Which library can I access XmlRpcValue.h file?

Tags: ros, geometry, xmlrpc, cmake, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

While installing geometry package for tf, during catkin_make I receive error:

21%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 21%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 22%] Built target test_roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 25%] Built target test_roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 27%] Built target test_roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target test_roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 32%] Built target test_roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] Built target test_rosmaster_generate_messages_cpp
[ 36%] Built target test_rosmaster_generate_messages_lisp
[ 37%] Built target test_rosmaster_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 37%] Built target test_rosservice_generate_messages_lisp
[ 37%] Built target test_rosservice_generate_messages_eus
[ 38%] Built target test_rosmaster_generate_messages_eus
[ 38%] Built target test_rosservice_generate_messages_cpp
[ 38%] Built target test_rosservice_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 40%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_cpp
[ 41%] Built target test_rosmaster_generate_messages_py
[ 41%] Built target test_rosservice_generate_messages_py
[ 41%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 42%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_py
[ 43%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_lisp
[ 43%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_eus
[ 45%] Built target test_rosbag_generate_messages_eus
[ 45%] Built target test_rosbag_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 46%] Built target test_rosbag_generate_messages_lisp
[ 47%] Built target test_rosbag_generate_messages_py
[ 48%] Built target test_rosbag_generate_messages_cpp
[ 50%] Built target test_rostopic_generate_messages_cpp
[ 50%] Built target test_rostopic_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 50%] Built target test_rostopic_generate_messages_eus
[ 51%] Built target test_rostopic_generate_messages_py
[ 52%] Built target test_rostopic_generate_messages_lisp
[ 52%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[ 52%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 52%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 53%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[ 53%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 53%] Built target amcl_sensors
[ 53%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 53%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 53%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_py
[ 53%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 53%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_eus
[ 53%] Built target hector_mapping_generate_messages_py
[ 53%] Built target hector_mapping_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 53%] Built target hector_mapping_generate_messages_cpp
[ 53%] Built target hector_mapping_generate_messages_lisp
[ 53%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_cpp
[ 53%] Built target hector_mapping_generate_messages_eus
[ 53%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 55%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_eus
[ 55%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_py
[ 55%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_lisp
[ 55%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_cpp
[ 55%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 55%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_lisp
[ 55%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_eus
[ 55%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_py
[ 55%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_cpp
[ 55%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 56%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_py
[ 56%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_eus
[ 57%] Built target rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_lisp
[ 58%] Built target rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_py
[ 58%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_lisp
[ 60%] Built target rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_cpp
[ 61%] Built target rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_eus
[ 61%] Built target scanmatcher
[ 62%] Built target rtabmap_ros_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 62%] Built target hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages
[ 62%] Built target rosconsole
[ 62%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages
[ 62%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages
[ 62%] Built target test_roslib_comm_generate_messages
[ 62%] Built target tf2_msgs_gencpp
[ 62%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages
[ 62%] Built target test_rosmaster_generate_messages
[ 62%] Built target test_roscpp_generate_messages
[ 65%] Built target test_rospy_generate_messages_py
[ 67%] Built target test_rospy_generate_messages_eus
[ 67%] Built target test_rosservice_generate_messages
[ 68%] Built target test_rospy_generate_messages_cpp
[ 70%] Built target test_rospy_generate_messages_lisp
[ 71%] Built target test_rospy_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 71%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target test_rosbag_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target tf_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target test_rostopic_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target tf_gencpp
[ 71%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target hector_mapping_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target navfn_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target rtabmap_ros_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target gridfastslam
[ 71%] Built target test_rospy_generate_messages
[ 71%] Built target tf2
[ 71%] Built target tf2_py
[ 75%] Built target roscpp
[ 75%] Built target laser_scan_sparsifier
[ 75%] Built target voxel_grid
[ 75%] Built target message_filters
[ 75%] Built target rosout
[ 75%] Built target laser_scan_splitter
[ 75%] Built target topic_tools
[ 75%] Built target geotiff_writer
[ 75%] Built target laser_scan_sparsifier_node
[ 75%] Built target DepthImageToLaserScan
[ 75%] Built target laser_scan_sparsifier_nodelet
[ 75%] Built target laser_scan_splitter_node
[ 75%] Built target laser_scan_splitter_nodelet
[ 75%] Built target tf2_ros
[ 75%] Built target mux
[ 75%] Built target map_to_image_node
[ 76%] Built target demux
[ 76%] Built target drop
[ 76%] Built target relay
[ 76%] Built target throttle
[ 76%] Built target switch_mux
[ 77%] Built target DepthImageToLaserScanROS
[ 77%] Built target rosbag
[ 77%] Built target tf2_ros_buffer_server
[ 77%] Built target tf2_ros_static_transform_publisher
[ 77%] Built target tf
[ 77%] Built target pytf_py
[ 77%] Built target pointcloud_to_laserscan
[ 77%] Built target geotiff_node
[ 77%] Built target play
[ 77%] Built target record
[ 77%] Built target ZEDWrapper
[ 77%] Built target geotiff_saver
[ 77%] Built target hector_geotiff_plugins
[ 77%] Built target DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet
[ 77%] Building CXX object geometry/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/src/change_notifier.cpp.o
[ 77%] Built target testBroadcaster
[ 77%] Built target tf_empty_listener
[ 77%] Built target static_transform_publisher
[ 77%] Built target depthimage_to_laserscan
[ 77%] Built target tf_monitor
[ 77%] Built target testListener
[ 77%] Built target tf_echo
[ 78%] Built target fake_localization
[ 78%] Built target transform_listener_unittest
[ 78%] Built target slam_gmapping
[ 80%] Built target imu_attitude_to_tf_node
[ 80%] Built target slam_gmapping_nodelet
[ 80%] Built target slam_gmapping_replay
Scanning dependencies of target hector_trajectory_server
Scanning dependencies of target map_server_image_loader
Scanning dependencies of target map_server-map_saver
[ 80%] Built target pose_and_orientation_to_imu_node
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/map_server/rtest
[ 81%] Built target hector_map_server
[ 81%] Building CXX object hector_slam/hector_trajectory_server/CMakeFiles/hector_trajectory_server.dir/src/hector_trajectory_server.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target ncd_parser
Scanning dependencies of target amcl
[ 81%] Building CXX object navigation/map_server/CMakeFiles/map_server_image_loader.dir/src/image_loader.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target laser_ortho_projector
[ 81%] Building CXX object scan_tools/ncd_parser/CMakeFiles/ncd_parser.dir/src/ncd_parser.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object navigation/map_server/CMakeFiles/map_server-map_saver.dir/src/map_saver.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object navigation/amcl/CMakeFiles/amcl.dir/src/amcl_node.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object scan_tools/laser_ortho_projector/CMakeFiles/laser_ortho_projector.dir/src/laser_ortho_projector.cpp.o
[ 81%] Built target rtest
Scanning dependencies of target laser_scan_matcher
[ 81%] Building CXX object scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/CMakeFiles/laser_scan_matcher.dir/src/laser_scan_matcher.cpp.o
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/geometry/tf/src/change_notifier.cpp:34:25: fatal error: XmlRpcValue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
geometry/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'geometry/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/src/change_notifier.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [geometry/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/src/change_notifier.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:37905: recipe for target 'geometry/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [geometry/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 81%] Linking CXX executable /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/map_server/map_saver
[ 81%] Built target map_server-map_saver
[ 82%] Linking CXX shared library /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmap_server_image_loader.so
[ 82%] Built target map_server_image_loader
[ 82%] Linking CXX executable /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ncd_parser/ncd_parser
[ 82%] Built target ncd_parser
[ 82%] Linking CXX executable /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/hector_trajectory_server/hector_trajectory_server
[ 82%] Built target hector_trajectory_server
[ 82%] Linking CXX executable /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/amcl/amcl
[ 82%] Built target amcl
[ 82%] Linking CXX shared library /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/liblaser_ortho_projector.so
[ 82%] Built target laser_ortho_projector
[ 82%] Linking CXX shared library /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/liblaser_scan_matcher.so
[ 82%] Built target laser_scan_matcher
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

I know it is because a library is missing, I install xmlprc library, but not sure why it still gives error. Anyone know which library this file is related to?

Ps: I have done sudo apt-get-upgrade and sudo apt-get update as well.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260022/which-library-can-i-access-xmlrpcvalue.h-file?/) by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-04-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
Please post the complete output of catkin_make.

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2017-04-24**:
I have updates the question with as much I can retrieve for catkin_make

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
Why can't you post the rest of the catkin_make output? If necessary, change your terminal settings to buffer more output.

What packages are you trying to build in your workspace? Can you also post their CMakeLists.txt files?

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2017-04-26**:
Thanks, I needed to change the terminal settings for more output. However I figured out what the issue was. I was trying to build geometry package, which is dependent on the basic ros package ros_comm. However, if you install ros_comm through catkin build it will create conflict for geometry.

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2017-04-26**:
This is because the ros_comm is already installed when ROS was initially installed, so the file was not being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out what the issue was. I was trying to build geometry package, which is dependent on the basic ros package ros_comm. However, if you install ros_comm through catkin build it will create conflict for geometry. This is because the ros_comm is already installed when ROS was initially installed, so the file was not being read.

---

Originally posted by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) with karma: 36 on 2017-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-05-01**:
I'm glad you got it working there's a thread here that looks related: https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/144 With an upstream change here that might effect it for others with similar problems. https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/962

**Comment by [Ay Ay Ron](https://answers.ros.org/users/31214/ay-ay-ron/) on 2017-07-16**:
Could you please provide the steps that you took to resolve the issue once you identified it?  I'm currently running into the same issue, but unfortunately I don't have the wherewithal to get things to build... thanks!